# A function called that takes two lists as its parameters and returns either True or False. Python

Tags: python, list, function

I start to know Python recently. This is what I'm working on. Please give a hint how to start.

Write a function called `sameElements` that takes two lists as its parameters and returns either True or False. It should return True when the second list is just a rearrangement of the first list, meaning that the second list has exactly the same elements, just in a different (or possibly even the same) order. You can assume data items in the two lists are of the same type.

For example:

```
sameElements([1,2,3], [2,3,1])
True
sameElements([1,2,3], [3,2,2])
False
sameElements([1,2,3], [3,2,1,1])
False
sameElements([1,1,2], [1,2,1])
True
sameElements([1,1,2], [2,1])
False
sameElements(['a','c','a','b'], ['b','a','a','c'])
True
```

Note that:

- The answer will always be False for lists that are not the same length.
- Your function should not modify either of the lists, so you may need to make a copy of one or more of the lists.
- Duplicates are allowed and need to appear the same number of times in both lists.

Comment: Show us what you've tried (code preferably, or at least a thought process). People here don't really like to just write the code for you; plus, you'll learn more if you at least take a crack at it.

Comment: Try to sort elements of each list and then check if two lists are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a hint for you

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['a','c','a','b']) == Counter(['b','a','a','c'])
True
```

But you're probably going to tell us you can't use `Counter`

Comment: Hint: Implement your own `Counter`.